# Localization of Smooth Functions on R

Tags: functions, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, localization

Consider the ring of functions $C^{k}(\mathbb{R}^d;\mathbb{R}^d)$ from $\mathbb{R}^d$ to itself with $k$-continuous derivatives.  Is the localization of $C^{k}(\mathbb{R}^d;\mathbb{R}^d)$ at the ideal $(0)$ a field?

If so, is this object ever studied?

Comment: I'm a bit rusty on this, so I thought to ask.  I haven't touched commutative algebra in 6 years.

Comment: For $d=1$, $R =C^k(\Bbb{R})$ with pointwise addition/multiplication is a commutative ring with unity, $I=\{f\in R,f(0)=0\}$ is an ideal, $R/I=\{f+I,f\in R\}$ is a ring with operations $(f+I)+(g+I)=(f+g)+I,(f+I)(g+I)=fg+I$, and we have an isomorphism $\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}1_R\to R/I$. The localization is the ring $R_I=\{\{\frac{fh}{gh},h\in R,h\not\in I\},f,g\in R,g\not \in I\}$. Taking $h$ vanishing everywhere except on a neighborhood of $0$ shows that $R_I\cong R/J$ is the ring of germs, with $J$ the ideal of functions vanishing on some neighborhood of $0$.

Comment: Oh true, thanks.